# Mapped nested component doesn't work peopetly (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a list of items mapped to be displayed on my "allItems" page. Now every Item has a button that fires up a modal with the specs of the item, but this modal display the same value for all the item (the last one in the array).
I tried to pass the id in toggle func but it doesn't work.

Anyone knows how can I display the same data in the Card and the Modal?

Here's my code:

```
 state = {
        modal: false,
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        })
    }
 render(){
 return(
 {rooms.map(({ _id, name, descr, prezzo }) => (
                        <>
                        <Card key={_id} className="rooms-card-template">
                            <CardImg />
                            <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle>{name}</CardTitle>
                                <CardText>{descr}</CardText>
                                <CardSubtitle>{prezzo}$/notte</CardSubtitle>
                                <Button onClick={this.toggle}>Apri Annuncio</Button>
                                
                                <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
                                    <ModalHeader >{name}</ModalHeader>
                                    <ModalBody>
                                        {descr}
                                        <h5 style={{ paddingTop: "10px"}}>Riepilogo prenotazione</h5>
                                        <Form>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Label>Struttura:</Label>
                                                <Input value={name}/>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Label>Ospiti:</Label>
                                                <Input type="select"name="ospiti" id="ospiti">
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                    <option>4</option>
                                                    <option>5</option>
                                                    <option>6</option>
                                                    <option>7</option>
                                                    <option>8</option>
                                                    <option>9</option>
                                                </Input>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Label>Check in</Label>
                                                <Input type="date" name="checkin-date" id="checkin-date" placeholder="Check in" />
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup className="rooms-checkout">
                                                <Label>Check out</Label>
                                                <Input type="date" name="checkout-date" id="checkout-date" placeholder="Check out" /> 
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            { isAuth ? userAuth : userUnauth }
                                        </Form>
                                    </ModalBody>
                                </Modal>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>

                        </>
                    ))}
)
}
```

Comment: You've only a single modal toggle state value, so the condition `isOpen={this.state.modal}` is true for all at the same time and the last mapped element is the one setting the modal content. You were onto the right idea with passing an id to the toggle handler. Just need to store that instead and check for the matching condition when opening the modal.

Comment: You could have an ```openModal()``` function where you set the ```state``` of ```isOpen``` and a```spectatedProduct state``` with the clicked element's values.
So you don't need to loop render multiple modals, just 1 with changing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You've a single boolean `modal` state that all the modals cue from. When `this.state.modal` is true then a modal is rendered and opened for each element being mapped.

## Solution

Instead of storing a boolean value for whether or not a modal should be open you should store an `id` when you want a specific modal to open.

```
state = {
  modal: null // <-- null, non-id state value
};

toggle = (id) => () => { // <-- curried function handler
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    modal: prevState.modal === id ? null : id // <-- set new id or toggle off
  }));
};

render() {
  return (
    <>
      {rooms.map(({ _id, name, descr, prezzo }) => (
        <Card key={_id} className="rooms-card-template">
          ...
          <CardBody>
            ...
            <Button
              onClick={this.toggle(_id)} // <-- pass id
            >
              Apri Annuncio
            </Button>

            <Modal
              isOpen={this.state.modal === _id} // <-- open if id is match
              toggle={this.toggle(_id)} // <-- pass id
            >
              ...
            </Modal>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```